# Use Powershell to login to DirectAdmin

Tags: powershell

im trying to login to my hostings DirectAdmin page using Powershell. However I can't seem to get arround the Login button. Tried several ways to submit the forum but all did nothing.

Does anyone know the correct line of code to login or do a login attempt?

```
$url = "http://perkele.nl:2222/"
$username = "**"
$password = "**"
$ie = New-Object -com InternetExplorer.Application
$ie.visible = $true; 
$ie.navigate($url); 

$ie.Document.getElementByID('username').value=$username
$ie.Document.getElementByID("password").value=$password
```

Submitting the username and password goes fine. The Login button just doesnt seem to be a legitimate submit button like usual forms have.

Any help is welcome, thanks!

Comment: You can view the page source to find out what the button is. The code for the button is `<td class=listtitle align=right colspan=2><input type=submit value='Login'></td>`. It is, in fact, an ordinary submit button. JPBlanc's answer should work.

Comment: In fact, it *does* work. I just tested it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to add this line at the botton of your script :

```
$ie.Document.getElementById("form").submit()
```

Comment: Allright, thanks for the answer JPBlanc. Thats what I was looking for. Tried several things but im a little new into this IE powershell scripting. Thanks!